# Photo limit for each field on the form

Tags: jquery

I have a form, where the user clicks "Add new color", a new field is added automatically. See below:

[image]

Each field will be limited to 6 photos. But the code is calculating all fields at the same time and not individually. How do I have each field calculated individually and not all at the same time?

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" >
    <tr class="linhas">
    <td>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Código de cores</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Cor Básica</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #367FA9; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold">Grades</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 40%"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Referência"></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 30%">
<select name="CoresBasicas" class="form-control">
<?php echo $metodos->comboCores($key); ?>
</select>       
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="Grades[]" class="form-control grades" style="width: 100%">
    <?php echo $metodos->comboGrades($key); ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">    
<div class="mostrarGrades"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="text-left">
<label for='files' class="upload">Selecionar fotos <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
<input id='files' type='file' name="Fotos[]" multiple>
</td>
</table>
</td>
<td  style="padding: 5px"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
</tr>              
<tr><td colspan="3" class="text-right">
<button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-success" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Incluir nova cor</button>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
var count=0;
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
        count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

        if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 6 || count > 7) {
            alert("O máximo é de até 6 fotos");
            count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
               if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                     continue;
               }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<input type="radio" name="FotoPrincipal[]" id="principal" value="'+escape(theFile.name)+'"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" style="width: 30%"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }
    $('#files').change(function(evt){
        handleFileSelect(evt);
    });
    $('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
        $(this).parent('span').remove();
      count--;

            if(count==0){
        $('#files').val(null);
      }
    });
    $('#list').on('click', '#principal',function () {
        document.getElementById("botao").disabled = "";
        document.getElementById("texto").style.display = "none";
    });
</script>
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: the solution is when `Add new color` make random **unique id**, then you call which unique id.

Comment: You have same id for files input i.e : `id='files'` instead use class .

Comment: it must be unique like `id='files_xjfuehf'` because multiple `Add new color` so every files unique id

Comment: `var $fileUpload` you can use click function get the id from where files upload input